# Equivalent of should be_true in minitest

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest

I would like to know the equivalent of:

```
event.should be_live
```

in Minitest? The method I am testing is:

```
event.live?
```

At the moment I am using:

```
conf.live?.must_equal true
```

But it looks to me quite contrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of minitest allow testing predicates in `assert_operator`. The expectation for that in the spec DSL is `must_be`. So your code can look like:

```
event.must_be :live?
```